# are calendarId, eventId in the google calendar API same as android provider API?

Tags: google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Using the android calendar provider, you can query event instances, which contain a calendarId value and an eventId value. Are these values the same as those you would get if you queried directly using the google calendar API?

For example, each time you clear your calendar data and then sync, will the calendarId and eventId values be the same as the prior time, that is persistent? Or will they be regenerated locally by the provider with some mapping going back to the corresponding events in the actual google calendar?

In other words, for a given user, is the pair [calendarId, eventId] effectively a persistent UID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not the same. The Android calendar and event IDs are row ids in the underlying SQLite tables and incremented automatically whenever a new calendar or event is inserted.

Check out how the event and calendar`_ID` columns are created in [CalendarDatabaseHelper.java, line 523](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/CalendarProvider/+/android-p-preview-4/src/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarDatabaseHelper.java#523) and [CalendarDatabaseHelper.java, line 767](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/CalendarProvider/+/android-p-preview-4/src/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarDatabaseHelper.java#767). Note that for calendars it doesn't specify `AUTOINCREMENT` explicitly, but if no `_ID` is specified when inserting a calendar it's determined automatically (see [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) ).

Any similarities to the Google API IDs are pure coincidence.

**Edit:**

Addressing your comment about having a UID to identify same elements:

For events there is a common ID, see [iCalUID](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#iCalUID) and [UID_2445](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns#UID_2445). These are essentially the same fields and I'd expect them to have the same value for the same events.

Note, even though the field is called `UID_2445` on Android, it's the same field as in RFC 5545 because RFC 5545 is the successor of RFC 2445 and the UID field has the same meaning in both specs.

Comment: Thank you. That appears to be sufficient to prove they are not the same. Too bad they aren't - it would be nice to have some sort of UUID.

Comment: At least for events there is a common ID, see [iCalUID]https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#iCalUID) and [UID_2445](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns#UID_2445). RFC 5545 is the successor of RFC 2445 and the `UID` field has the same meaning in both specs.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the common ID field of both APIs.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed iCalUID field, but it seems to be always blank in Anrdoid calendar. At any rate, not reliable.